# MySQL Regex - Find where there are 10 numbers in a row in a field

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to find records where there are 10 numbers in a row in the field. e.g. 1234567890, 8884265555 etc.  The field will contain text as well so I need to see if any 10-digit strings exist anywhere within the field.

I have got this far...

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE detail REGEXP '[0-9]{10}'
```

My that returns where there 10 numbers *anywhere* in the field instead of all in a row.  I am trying to detect phone numbers.  Thanks!

Comment: That's strange, the REGEXP says 10 in a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression `[0-9]{10}` does imply that ten digits in a row (only) should be matched. So, your issue must be elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry guys... Yes it actually working I just missed it!  I have asked moderators to delete this question.